# Inadvertant Sin of Prohibited Food or Relations

Tags: halacha, food, korban, arayot, chelev

What is the explanation of the talmudic dictum (Sanhedrin 62b, Kreisos 19b) that one who inadvertently sins in the areas of forbidden foods or sexual relations (e.g. reaches for kosher food, misses it and instead puts non-kosher in his mouth) must bring a korban chatas because "he received pleasure" even though other sins would be exempt from a korban in this case? What characteristic do these sins share that gives them a this unique legal status? How are these sins different from e.g. shatnez which seems to also dependent on pleasure (see Yevamos 4b)?

Some Acharonim (e.g. R. Elchonon Wasserman in Kovetz Shiurim) explain that the prohibition is actually the pleasure itself, not the act, so the disconnect from the act through lack of intent doesn't exempt them. I wondered if Rishonim hold of this or perhaps have some chiddush about korban chatas, or perhaps a different explanation.

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: These sins intrinsically involve bodily enjoyment (contrast, e.g., with stealing, hitting someone, slandering someone, or violating Shabbos, where the sin itself does not intrinsically involve bodily enjoyment).

Comment: @Fred I know but a) other sins such as shatnez also involve bodily benefit b) what is the Gemaras source that one would be obligated in a chatas. (Acharonim explain this to be because the prohibition is actually the hanaa not the act itself so their disconnect from the act through lack of intent doesnt exempt them. I wondered if Rishonim hold of this or perhaps have some chiddush about korban chatas, or perhaps a different explanation).

Comment: @mevaqesh Your question would be greatly clarified and improved by including all that (I, for one, would upvote it then).

Comment: +1. That's a helpful edit, but I think it would be good to also include the point about *sha'atnez* (since that *isur* is dependent on *hana'as haguf*, see e.g. *Y'vamos* 4b), which is an example that might seem to indicate that חלבים ועריות are not in an exclusive category. More importantly, I think your question would be further improved by explaining the nature of what you mean by "inadvertent sin" here (מתעסק, e.g. per Rashi's explanation that the person was going for *mutar* piece or that the person thought that the piece was *shuman*).

Comment: The bodily enjoyment of Shatnez is external, whilst the bodily enjoyment of Sexual relations and eating something is internal.

Comment: @GershonGold While I definitely think you could draw a halachic distinction between the former and the latter, I don't think external vs. internal is an apt distinction (phrased as such). In any case, the *hana'as haguf* required to violate *sha'atneiz* is at least superficially similar enough to the other two that it is reasonable to demand either a direct source or a compelling halachic argument with sources to distinguish between them with respect to *mis'aseik*.

Comment: Wait, I'm very confused.  Is shaatnez a chiyuv kareit?  I'm pretty sure it's not.

Comment: Could it be because food and relations are the two most basic primordial pleasures to humans?

Answer (score 1):

One can characterize the general rule of "mis'asek" as stating that an act is not attributable to a person if the person lacks a conscious state of mind associating him to the act. An inadvertent act is disconnected from and thus not attributed to the person because the person had no conscious, mental connection to it. For an act to be associated to you it must be a conscious act.

Things which involve pleasure, such as eating and sexual relations, are by definition not mis'asek, because pleasure is a conscious state. Any act which involves pleasure is thus by definition a conscious act.

Answer (score 0):

**Asvun De'Oraisah** (R' Yosef Engel, 19th C., *siman* 24) gives a similar approach to R' Elchanan- pleasure-based sins have no "disconnect" through lack of intention.

However, see Rosh Hashana 28a (at the end of the page), which states that *kavana* for *mitzvos* should not be needed for *mitzvas matza*, "**as he ate**". Rashi explains:

"And he benefited, so it's not *mitsasek*, just like with **prohibited foods and relations**."

R' Yosef Engel points out that according to his own approach, Rashi is impossible to understand. He writes that it's unreasonable to say that *mitzvas matzo* requires one to be derive pleasure from the *matza*, so the comparison to prohibited foods/relations cannot be made.

It would seem that Rashi understands that pleasure **in itself** prevents the disconnect between the act and the person, preventing the *p'tur* of* *mis'asek*. As such it is relevant even to *matza*, as there too pleasure is experienced and disconnect prevented.

(As an aside, Rashi is, even without this, difficult to understand- *kavana* for mitzvos is not just needed to "connect" to the act- even intending the act is not enough if it isn't done *leshem mitzva*, *vetzarich iyun*.)

Comment: +1 for Rashi but it remains difficult. The pleasure ought to alert you to an experience; but adds no clarification of whether it is a permissible or forbidden experience.

Comment: @mevaqesh ; the pleasure "alerts"/connects you to the act, so an aveira will remain an aveirah and a mitzva will remain a mitzva.